# Хранение 3d мира в файле

Tags: файлы, 3d, хранение-данных

Я сейчас пишу небольшой клон Minecraft. Мир состоит только из кубов. Мне нужно хранить мир в файле. В 2d варианте это выглядит так:

```
1 1 1 0 
1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

А как это делается в 3d?

Comment: Мне кажется, мой ответ далеко не исчерпывающий. Стоит подождать кого-нибудь, кто разбирается в подобных вещах.

Comment: ок, снимаю галочку

Comment: Я так понимаю, если мир не делится строго на заполняемые кубы, то нужно хранить отдельно объекты: расположение по xyz, направление, состояние (если такое присуще).

Comment: Нет, он представляет собой лишь кубы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нотч использовал [NBT](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/NBT_format) - архив с иерархической структорой, где каждый узел имеет один из одиннадцати типов (см. ссылку), что позволяет хранить любые данные: блоки, их метаданные, освещение, сущности, кастомные свойства кастомных объектов и вообще все что угодно.

Если вам это не надо, то простейший вариант - запилить все в бинарник. Нет необходимости хранить именно двух- или трехмерный массив. Разверните его в одномерный, напрмер:

```
chunkkSize = 16; // как "батько" учил :D
blocks[x, y, z] -> blocks[x  + y * chunkSize + z * chunkSize * chunkSize]
```

а при вычитке

```
int chunkSize = 16;
int chunkSizePow2 = chunkSize * chunkSize;
int chunkSizePow3 = chunkSizePow2 * chunkSize;
for (int i = 0; i < chunkSizePow3; i++)
{
    int x = i % chunkSize;
    int y = (i % chunkSizePow2) / chunkSize;
    int z = (i % chunkSizePow3) / chunkSizePow2;
}
```

Размер чанка подставьте свой, но как по мне 16 вполне удобен.

Дешево, надежно и практично, хотя ручками не поправить.
Чтобы править ручками используйте тот же подход, но пишите id блоков в txt-файл через любой удобный разделитель.

Answer (score 2):

Если вы решили использовать именно такой вариант хранения данных, то просто введите ещё один разделитель (первый разделитель — перенос строки). Например, `&`:

```
1 1 1 0 
1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
&
1 1 1 0 
1 0 0 0
0 0 2 0
0 0 0 0
&
1 0 1 0 
1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

До первого знака `&` — объекты c `z=0`, между первым и вторым — c `z=1` и так далее.

Я не особо разбираюсь в подобных вещах, но данные в бинарном формате будут занимать меньше места и быстрее разбираться, а формат JSON или XML будет понятнее. В первом случае я бы просто хранил сжатый каким-либо стандартным алгоритмом список кубов с координатами и другими параметрами. Возможно, отсортированный, если это ускорит bulk load.

Comment: Спасибо! Но я просто привел пример. Мне все равно, как хранить. Это лучший способ?

Comment: @egordorichev, обновил ответ.